# IE11 Compabitility View settings, meta tag, x-ua-compatible response header, F12, all options work fine in one environment, NOT in another

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, vbscript

Old (OLD!) legacy ASP web application. Recent upgrade of the server from Windows 2003 Server to Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.

One particular page which uses MPC (multipage control?), tabbed control, displays all messed up in IE11.

[image]

I have tried these options:

1. F12 Developer toolbar, set Document Mode to 5.
   Local environment result: Worked beautifully.
   Client environment result: Nope. Still messed up.
2. I added meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5"> to the page
   Local environment result: Worked beautifully.
   Client environment result: Nope. Still messed up.
3. Reset. I went into IIS, HTTP Response Headers and added X-UA-Compatible/IE=5.
   Local environment result: Worked beautifully.
   Client environment result: Nope. Still messed up.
4. Checked IE versions... I am on IE11, Update Version: 11.0.33. Client is on 11.0.32. But all of these steps worked on IE10 in our environment as well.

I also saw a thread about group policies and compatibility view settings. Is there something in a group policy on that client's environment that might be overriding anything else I have tried to do?

Can group policy even override F12 mode? (just searching for any possible explanation as to the differences in otherwise identical environments)

Comment: To improve this question, you need some code.  (this is a coding site)

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem in a debugging site?  like jsfiddle.com?

Comment: http://www.landofcode.com/online-code-editor.php is an online vbscript editor